# What size and kind of check valve do I need?

Tags: water, valve

I was told that I need a check valve for my washing machine hookup under the sink.
I understand that the check valve makes sure the water only flows in one direction.
I don't understand what kind of check valve I need. If I just put "check valve" into amazon, can I buy the first one I see? It seems to me that some of these valves are for fuel, not water.

Answer (score 1):

Check valves come in several sizes.

I have used 1/2" and 3/4" and even 1 1/2"…

Check the pressure rating some markets require 9 bar.

The design can be based on a ball or flap depending on the flowrate.

Important: do make sure that the valve is installed correctly for the flow direction. Seen some people struggle for hours when they fitted it wrong.

Comment: What should I check to find the pressure rating? And, where should I look to see the size I need? (Sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: The size will be defined by the pipes you are working with so you should be able to sort that.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems that I need 3/4 inch.

Comment: I know we don't do product recommendations, but can you link me an example, or show a picture so that I know for sure what we are talking about?

Comment: @Burt just make a trip to your lical plumbing or large diy store and ask for advice. Dare we assume you have the tools…

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate your help

Comment: If the answer did help you, why not up-tick or accept it?!